# Asserts folder mock jsons are not accessible on azure deployed angular webapp

Tags: json, angular, azure

I have an angular application deployed in azure webapp.
I have used mock jsons to load data for few apis, which are residing in assets/jsons folder.

I am able to access a text file which is residing in same path via url like below
*https://{myapp}.azurewebsites.net/assets/jsons/users.txt*

But when I try to access a json file which is residing in same path like below I am getting error
*https://{myapp}.azurewebsites.net/assets/jsons/insights.json*

> "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
> changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I have added that folder(s) to assets in angular.json

```
   "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/web",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/assets/jsons"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
```

Application is not working as it is not able to load the data from jsons.Can you please assist in overcoming this issue?

Comment: Are you referencing json file by relative or absolute path in your app? Can you paste how you call the file?

Comment: I am calling like this
 **readFromJsons(fileName: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('assets/jsons/' + fileName + '.json');
  }**
Which is working perfectly fine locally, but not on azure webapp after deployment, I verified, server does have the files present in that directory

Comment: Does this help https://javascript.plainenglish.io/adding-assets-to-our-angular-apps-in-azure-2d009ff7989 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a file with web.config under src/ with below contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And including it in angular.json ***assets*** section helped to get it fixed.

```
  "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
```

Thanks to [reference link](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/adding-assets-to-our-angular-apps-in-azure-2d009ff7989) provided by Misha Mashina.